# What is the purpose of port 1234/TCP running by 'systemd' with process id '1' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, security, firewall, ufw

When I used `$ nmap 192.168.1.X` it shows that `1234/tcp OPEN hotline` is open.

I am running behind firewall `ufw`, and there is no rule for port `1234`.

`$ lsof -i` showed that it is running by `systemd` with process-id `1`.

After some searching I came across [this link](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1234), which might be serious (Section from link below).

> `1234    tcp     trojan                KiLo, Ultors Trojan             Trojans`
> **`1234    tcp     hotline                                               SANS`**
> `1234    tcp     SubSevenJavaclient    [trojan] SubSeven Java client   SANS`
> `1234    tcp     UltorsTrojan          [trojan] Ultors Trojan          SANS`

What is the purpose of this port? Should I be concerned?

**Update:** I did a bit further investigation. Below are my findings.

1. `$ lsof -i | grep 1234` output:

```
systemd      1             root   57u  IPv6  36160      0t0  TCP *:1234 (LISTEN)
monopd    2154           nobody    3u  IPv6  36160      0t0  TCP *:1234 (LISTEN)
```

2. `$ whereis monopd` output:

```
monopd: /usr/sbin/monopd /etc/monopd.conf /usr/share/man/man6/monopd.6.gz
```

3. `$ man monopd` output [partial]:

```
monopd(6)                                                                       games                                                                       monopd(6)

NAME
       monopd - Monopoly™ like game server

SYNOPSIS
       monopd

DESCRIPTION
       monopd  is  a  dedicated  game server daemon for playing Monopoly-like board games like GtkAtlantic. Clients connect to the server and communicate using short
       commands and XML messages.
```

4. `$ cat /etc/monopd.conf` output [partial]:

```
# Monopd configuration file.
#

#
# Port which monopd should be listening to.
#
port=1234

#
# Metaserver host.
#
metaserverhost=meta.atlanticd.net

#
# Metaserver port.
#
metaserverport=1240
```

Further reading: [`monopd`](https://wiki.debian.org/Games/monopd) debian wiki

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers. Port 1234 is sometimes used by VLC media player. Are you using VLC?

Comment: @user535733 In that case is should not be running by `systemd`, right?

Comment: Correct. VLC media player is not usually run by systemd. Yes, you should be concerned. Were it my system, I would have already wiped it and reinstalled. I have no desire to be part of a botnet or cryptomining scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Removed monopd `$ sudo apt remove monopd`, which removed entry for port `1234` from `$ lsof -i` ouput.